# DataFrame: New column based on other column with string dictionary/json

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, dictionary

I have following pandas DataFrame with (I guess?) a string as a nested JSON in column "bucket".

```
    id      name    bucket
0   11324   Soaps   {"page":{"url":"https://www.url.com", "color":"white"} ...}
0   11325   Cans    {"page":{"url":"https://www.url.com", "color":"black"} ...}
0   11326   Boxes   {"page":{"url":"https://www.url.com", "color":"red"} ...}
```

Here are the dtypes:

```
dtypes
id                           int64
name                         object
bucket                       object
```

I wonder how I could access the values in column "bucket", so that I can create a new column with the respective value:

```
    id      name    bucket.                                                          color
0   11324   Soaps   {"web":{"project":"https://www.url1.com", "color":"white"} ...}  white
0   11325   Cans    {"web":{"project":"https://www.url2.com", "color":"white"} ...}  black
0   11326   Boxes   {"web":{"project":"https://www.url3.com", "color":"white"} ...}  red
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. `Series.str.extract`

We can use `extract` with `regex` pattern if the values in `bucket` column are of type `string`

```
df['color'] = df['bucket'].str.extract(r'"color":"([^"]+)"', expand=False)
```

#### 2. `Series.str.get`

Otherwise we can use `str.get` if the values in column `bucket` are of type `dict`

```
df['color'] = df['bucket'].str.get('page').str.get('color')
```

---

```
>>> df

      id   name                                                   bucket  color
0  11324  Soaps  {"page":{"url":"https://www.url.com", "color":"white"}}  white
0  11325   Cans  {"page":{"url":"https://www.url.com", "color":"black"}}  black
0  11326  Boxes    {"page":{"url":"https://www.url.com", "color":"red"}}    red
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `eval()` method and `apply()` method:

```
df['bucket']=df['bucket'].apply(lambda x:eval(x))
```

Now Finally:

```
df['color']=df['bucket'].apply(lambda x:list(x.values())[0]['color'])
```

Now If you print df you will get your desired output:

```
    id      name    bucket.                                                          color
0   11324   Soaps   {"web":{"project":"https://www.url1.com", "color":"white"} ...}  white
0   11325   Cans    {"web":{"project":"https://www.url2.com", "color":"white"} ...}  black
0   11326   Boxes   {"web":{"project":"https://www.url3.com", "color":"white"} ...}  red
```